# jQuery Smooth Div Scroll space issue in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to implement Thomas Khan's jQuery Smooth Div Scroll on a horizontal portfolio website. It works like a charm in Chrome, but in Firefox, the elements are spaced strangely.

I saw that the issue had been raised by someone else, and it apparently had to do with the fact that his images were in links, and had no specified width, which made the javascript struggle with width calculation. My website falls in the same category, but the solution that the other person found (removing the links to have simply a list of images) won't work for me.
I would like the scrolling divs to be filled with different kinds of contents which always fill the whole height of the navigator, for example a horizontal image with the legend appearing on hover, a vertical one, then two horizontal ones with a height of 50% stacked over one another, then a column of text, etc.

The plugin really seems to allow that with the right css (in Chrome, it would probably be done already), but I don't know how to solve the Firefox matter.

The page with the (shamefully messy) jquery, html and css can be found [here](http://sandielevent.com/gig-posters/).

If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late, but I have just had a similar issue and fixed it. now I do know what it's like to find these questions and not finding answers so hereby, for me, it was this:

Give all the divs a min-width that won't do any damage.

That's all.

In my case min-width:300px; did the trick!